# What services required to use webkitSpeechRecognition in Chrome Android

Tags: webkit, speech-recognition, google-chrome-app, webkitspeechrecognition

I am using Android board with Android 4.4.2
On OS`board not installed any services of google`. But now I want to use `webkitSpeechRecognition` in  chrome browser on this board. I installed Chrome Android but not working. What webkit is required for it to work?
Help?
Microphone allowed and have icon of nofication
I think it needs other service to speech to text 
Plz help me